# (Image in loop) Huge array of images and wants to display if image is really present then show the images otherwise delete/hide the image node

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image

**I have a huge array of images**

Actually I am  bit worry about checking the image that really exist and also want do something if image present
and if not found I am doing some other work.

***Note:*** **If one image is checking on server and takes 3 minutes
then how to handle in loop for other images.**

I am just found below image if image not exist :-

[image]

Please give a standard way that can be used for nth number of images in array.

```
var urlArray =  [{productImage:'http://www.queness.com/resources/images/png/appleeeeeee_ex.png'},{productImage:'https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'},{productImage:'https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_cooooooolor_272x92dp.png'},{productImage:'https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'}];

<div>
  <img src="">  // actually this comes through urlArray  
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check image URL exist or not, You can try this with javaScript,
It will check all URLs one by one and call the callBack function, then it will call URL check for next URL.
Next URL will be check after one completes, no matter how much time it will take.

```
function isImageExists(imgSrc, callBackAfterCheck) {
   var img = new Image();
   img.onload = function() { callBackAfterCheck(true) };
   img.onerror = function() {callBackAfterCheck(false) };
   img.src = imgSrc;
}

var urlArray = [{productImage:'http://www.queness.com/resources/images/png/appleeeeeee_ex.png'},{productImage:'https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'},{productImage:'https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_cooooooolor_272x92dp.png'},{productImage:'https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'}];


var imageIndex = 0;
function callBackAfterCheck(status){
   if(status == true){
     //do your stuff here
     console.log('image Exist');
   }else{
     //do your stuff here
    console.log('image not Exist');
   }
   imageIndex++
   if(imageIndex < urlArray.length){
     var imageUrl = urlArray[imageIndex].productImage;
     isImageExists(imageUrl, callBackAfterCheck)
   }
}

var imageUrl = urlArray[imageIndex].productImage;
isImageExists(imageUrl, callBackAfterCheck);
```

Here you can pass your image source and the function you want to execute after checking the source.
It will check your image existence and you can get the status (true or false) in your callBack function, 
Now you can do your stuff according to your need in callback function.